# How to target img src with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image

I have an hidden div with some menu items and a img src which is empty. A user can upload an image which will fill the img src and then I want to show the menu.

I've tried this, but I think this does not work because it does not check the img src.

```
$("#prev_img").change(function(){
  $("#menu").show();
});
```

I tried another way using the src lenght, but also no succes.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you. Do you want to show the `#menu` everytime the `src` attribute of `#prev_img` changes?

Comment: The best solution is that when there's something in the img src then show the #menu, otherwise hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `onchange` event for HTMLImageElement, but in your situation I think you can probably try to use `onload` event instead:

```
$("#prev_img").load(function() {
    $("#menu").show();
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hjk6r/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image attribute, use this:

```
$("#prev_img").change(function(){
  $("#menu img[src='some_attr']").show();
});
```

Or you can try this:

```
$('#menu').find('img[src=some_attribute_value_for_source').show();
```

http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/ jQuery Attribute Selector

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ jQuery Attribute value selector

```
$("[attribute='value']")
```

Selects and element with attribute of the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can always retrieve the img source by

`$("img").attr("src")`

And implement any checks on that, for example:

```
if( $("img").attr("src") != "" ){
   $("#menu").show();
}
```

Comment: How do I implement a check on that? If I put a `$("img").attr("src").change(function(){
  $("#menu").show();
});`

I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'change' `

Comment: @PeterBoomsma that's because the src attr of an image can't just change on its own. If your user is uploading the image through php you will get a page refresh (and thus you can show/hide your menu through php) or if you are using Ajax, you just need to put the `show()` code in your success function.

Comment: I've added an example for a check whether the source is empty or not. You can use this code to check right after you load the page.